# C++/ Dynamic Assignment

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Create `*Std` as a global variable.

Create `*Std` as many `Num` as you enter.

This code is not executed because `Num` is contained within `main()`.

Is there a way to set `*Std` as a global variable while getting `Num` input from `main()`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct s1 {
    string str1;
};

s1* Std = new s1[Num];

int main()
{
    cout << "How many [Std] do you want to create? : ";
    int Num;
    cin >>Num;

    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, Std[i].str1);
        cout << "\nStd["<<i<<"].str1 : " << Std[i].str1<<"\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to move `s1* Std = new s1[Num];` to after `cin >>Num;` and avoid using global variables.

Comment: @drescherjm I know that if I do, the code works. But I think it would be more convenient to set [*Std] as a global variable.

Comment: change `s1* Std = new s1[Num];` to `s1* Std{};` then put `Std = new s1[Num];` after `cin >>Num;`

Comment: @drescherjm It was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest to use a global variable at least one for your coding lifetime. Because the lesson learned when it is backfired is pretty meaningful.. At least I don't want to use it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables don't have to be initialized at the time they are declared.  You can separate declaration from assignment.

In this case, you can leave `Std` as a global variable, if you really want to (though, [globals are generally frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/), and in this case it is unnecessary since there are no other functions wanting to access `Std`), however you must move the `new[]` statement into `main()` after `Num` has been read in, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct s1 {
    string str1;
};

s1* Std;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many [Std] do you want to create? : ";
    int Num;
    cin >>Num;

    Std = new s1[Num];

    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, Std[i].str1);
        cout << "\nStd[" << i << "].str1 : " << Std[i].str1 << "\n\n";
    }

    delete[] Std;
}
```

That being said, you should use the standard [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container instead whenever you need a dynamic array, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct s1 {
    string str1;
};

vector<s1> Std;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many [Std] do you want to create? : ";
    int Num;
    cin >>Num;

    Std.resize(Num);

    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, Std[i].str1);
        cout << "\nStd[" << i << "].str1 : " << Std[i].str1 << "\n\n";
    }
}
```